Orca 6 Installation on MacBook Pro fails- ./setp: no such file or directory
I'm trying to install orca 6 for chemical computations. I'm using MacBook Pro with the M4 Max chip. I've tried using both
a)orca_6_0_1_linux_x86-64_shared_openmpi416_avx2.run. This gives:
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing ORCA 6.0.1 Installer ... ./orca_6_0_1_linux_x86-64_shared_openmpi416_avx2.run: line 542: /opt/local/bin/xz: Bad CPU type in executable
  100%  
./orca_6_0_1_linux_x86-64_shared_openmpi416_avx2.run: line 580: ./setup: No such file or directory

b)orca_6_0_1_macosx_arm64_openmpi411.run
This gives:
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing ORCA 6.0.1 Installer ..../orca_6_0_1_macosx_arm64_openmpi411.run: line 308: /opt/local/bin/bzip2: Bad CPU type in executable
 ... Decompression failed.
  100%  
./orca_6_0_1_macosx_arm64_openmpi411.run: line 704: ./setup: No such file or directory

Can someone help?

macOS isn't Linux, so Linux installers obviously won't work.
The macOS installer is running into a problem with the bzip2 executable:
line 308: /opt/local/bin/bzip2: Bad CPU type in executable ... Decompression failed

Which suggests the executable is an Intel version, not an ARM version. Your package manager (Macports?) needs to be updated/reconfigured so it installs ARM versions, but that's a different issue to solve.
You can try running the installer using the system-installed version of bzip2 by fixing $PATH:
env PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:$PATH ./orca_6_0_1_macosx_arm64_openmpi411.run

